# Facebook iOS SDK 3.5 accessToken invalid

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, facebook-access-token

I am using the following code to login on Facebook. I am using SDK 3.5.2.

```
    - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                          state:(FBSessionState)state
                          error:(NSError *)error
    {
        // FBSample logic
        // Any time the session is closed, we want to display the login controller (the user
        // cannot use the application unless they are logged in to Facebook). When the session
        // is opened successfully, hide the login controller and show the main UI.
        switch (state) {
            case FBSessionStateOpen: {

                NSMutableDictionary *params = [[[Singleton sharedSingleton] requestParams] mutableCopy];

                NSString *fbaccessToken = [session accessToken];
                NSLog(@"fbaccessToken: %@", fbaccessToken);

                [params setObject:fbaccessToken forKey:@"facebook_access_token"];


                [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [fbaccessToken length]] forKey:@"DEBUG_linghezza_fb_accessToken"];
                [params setObject:[[FBSession activeSession] appID] forKey:@"DEBUG_appID"];
                [params setObject:[[FBSession activeSession] urlSchemeSuffix] forKey:@"DEBUG_urlSchemeSuffix"];
                [params setObject:[[FBSession activeSession] permissions] forKey:@"DEBUG_permessi"];


                NSLog(@"%@", params);

                [[[Singleton sharedSingleton] sharedClient] postPath:@"login_with_facebook.json" parameters:params
                                                             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


                                                                 if ([[responseObject objectForKey:@"error"] isEqualToString:@"facebook_access_token not valid"]) {

                                                                     NSLog(@"closeAndClearTokenInformation");
                                                                     [session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                                                                     [session close];
                                                                     [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];

                                                                     NSLog(@"openSessionWithAllowLoginUI");
                                                                     [self openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];

                                                                     return;

                                                                 } else {...}
...

    }
    - (void)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
        NSLog(@"openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:allowLoginUI");
        [FBSession sessionOpenWithPermissions:[[[Singleton sharedSingleton] initPrefs] objectForKey:@"facebook_permissions"] completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
            [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];
        }];
        return;

}
```

When I change the password in Facebook, I cannot login any more. The server is receiving

```
{
    error: {
        message: "Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.",
        type: "OAuthException",
        code: 190,
        error_subcode: 460
    }
}
```

Everytime I try to refresh the token, I continue to receive the old token that the server cannot validate.

The server validates it with the following OpenGraph URI:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

How shall I fix this? Thank you

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing the same issue. Have you found the solution? Thanks